# get contact information for a particular email address

Tags: vbscript, outlook

I am trying to write a script that would

1. go through a list of email addresses from my domain
2. for each of these emails addressess get the display name and job title
3. output the email, display name, job title to a csv file

I am sure this is fairly simply, the only problem that I have here is that I have no idea how to access the contact card of a contact.

How do I pass the `strAddress` variable to a `olContactItem` object?

EDIT:
To improve the question - I don't know how can I view the contact of the existing user@mydomain.com from a list of email addresses in a csv file (not added to my contacts list or anything)

The code I have so far:

```
Const olContactItem = 2
strEmail = "user@mydomain.com"

set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set appOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set MyItem = appOutlook.CreateItem(olContactItem)
With MyItem
    .Email1Address = strEmail
    .jobTitle = strJobTitleVar
End With
```

I need to open the addess book page of that person, extract the values of Job Title and Display Name to relevant variables. However, I get stuck, because I get to a point where I am rather adding a new contact than viewing the existing person's info.

Is this more clear? How can I search through the address book for a particular person's info?

Comment: I am not sure what your question is; are you having problems retrieving the data from a GAL's AddressEntry object? Or setting various properties on a created ContactItem object?

Comment: I don't know how to call the ContactItem object for a particular email address and then retrieve several properties from this object, i.e. display name, title etc.

Comment: Use Namespace.CreateItem or MAPIFolder.Items.Add to create a ContactItem. You can then read various properties using either explicitly exposed properties (AddressEntry.Name etc.) or read raw Extended MAPI properties using AddressEntry.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty.

Comment: I have improved my question - is this more clear? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question - this seems to be doing everything I need:

```
strInputEmail = objInputFile.ReadLine
set appOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
set objNameSpace = appOutlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
set objContacts = objNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
Set objContact = objContacts.Items.Find("[IMAddress] = """ & strInputEmail & """")

strFullName = objContact.FullName
strJobTitle = objContact.JobTitle
strBusinessAddress = objContact.BusinessAddress
msgBox strFullName & strJobTitle & strBusinessAddress
```

It reads the inputfile, gets the email address as a variable, finds the person, gets the particular info as variables.

Thanks for help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the following lines. To see what the other properties and their DASL names are, look at the live GAL objects using [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author): either click IAddrBook button and drill down the container hierarchy or click IMAPISession | QueryIdentity to see the current user or (if you have a message with a particular recipient) click IMessage, go to the GetRecipientTable table, double on the recipient.
Once you have the IMailUser window, select the property that you need and look at the DASL edit box.

```
Const olContactItem = 2
strEmail = "user@mydomain.com"

set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set appOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
set NS = appOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
NS.Logon
set Recip = NS.CreateRecipient(strEmail)
Recip.Resolve
set AE = Recip.AddressEntry
Set MyItem = appOutlook.CreateItem(olContactItem)
With MyItem
    .Email1Address = strEmail
    'read PR_TITLE property
    .jobTitle = AE.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3A17001F")

End With
```